# PostgreSQL does not use all available IOPS on a single operation

Tags: performance, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows 7x64, CoreI7, SSD.

Assume a PostgreSQL table with 8 Int32 columns and following C# code to fill the table.

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("User Id=postgres;Password=**;host=localhost;database=**;"))
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "COPY \"MyTable\" FROM STDIN;";
    var copyInSerializer = new NpgsqlCopySerializer(connection);
    var copyIn = new NpgsqlCopyIn(command, connection, copyInSerializer.ToStream);
    copyIn.Start();

    for (int i = start; i < start + 1000000; i++)
    {
        copyInSerializer.AddInt32(i);
        //add 7 other int32 values
        copyInSerializer.EndRow();
    }
    copyInSerializer.Flush();
    copyIn.End();

    connection.Close();
}
```

On my test hardware this took ~10 seconds execution time and measured disk usage of ~20MB/s.
CPU and RAM do NOT hit limits.

The given SSD supports ~60MB/s writing random 4k blocks so I wondered why it would not execute faster. I created a second, identical table in the same database and disk and ran the above code sample in parallel (two tasks) on both tables.
Both took ~10 seconds, and Measured Disk usage was ~40MB/s.

Why does PostgreSQL not focus all available resources on the one and only operation happening?
Is there a way to force PostgreSQL to use the full available disk bandwidth?

Comment: Try setting `effective_io_concurrency = 6` or so.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Npgsql, but is this the right way to do a "bulk" operation, or is the code performing inserts row-by-row (= "slow-by-slow")?

Comment: I would recommend the book PostgreSQL High Performance as to answer that question would require a book. There are many variables in play.

Comment: @CraigRinger According to the documentation "Currently, this setting only affects bitmap heap scans." Doesn't this mean it would only help for queries?

Comment: Whatever the status of `effective_io_concurrency`, it might also be worth playing around with the other settings mentioned under http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-BACKGROUND-WRITER And please report here with your findings.

Comment: What is disk usage when you simply use `psql` and a dump file to copy data from?

Comment: @Colin'tHart You're right - no effect here, this is a `COPY FROM`. Teach me not to read the question properly...

Comment: I'm wondering if your program is producing the data fast enough for Pg to consume it. If, for testing, you write the data to a CSV file then use `COPY FROM`, does that perform closer to what you expect? If so, you might need a producer/consumer in your app, where one thread produces values and the other feeds them to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Still, this smells to me like "slow-by-slow" (thanks @Colin :-), couldn't be the most "performant" way to write to disk, couldn't it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware 'Copy to/from' is the fastest way to insert data into Postgres. My tests show that it is ~3 times faster than SQL [Insert Into...Values(..),(..)]. I'd be glad if there is any faster way.

Comment: It appears that the bottle neck is somewhere in the C# code. Fireing 'Copy MyTable From C:\test.csv' is about 2,5 times faster. Maybe NpgsqlCopySerializer is the culprit. I'll investigate for alternatives and let you know about further insights..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.NET (used in the code sample) obviously communicates via network - even if a local Postgres instance is used. Using STDIN therefore results in quite a bit overhead. Before Postgres is able to insert the bulk data, it needs to be:

- serialized by C# client
- transmitted via network connection (in my case to localhost)
- deserialized by Postgres

This basically explains/justifies the described behaviour.

If the C# Client and Postgres are run on the same computer, you can speed up bulk inseration by writing a csv file on a local ssd drive (even better a ram drive) and execute the SQL statement 'Copy MyTable From x:\test.csv'.

Comment: So where's the bottleneck then? All of serialization, sending over loopback interface, and deserialization should be CPU bound but OP said CPU was not at the limit.